# Как лучше оформить данное предложение?

Tags: запятые, орфоэпия, тире-или-двоеточие

*, среди последователей которых,  такие известные личности как  -- Стив Джобс из Apple,  Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило из Yahoo!.*

Comment: 1.Стив Джобс из Apple, а также из Yahoo! — Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило. 2. Стив Джобс из Apple, а также Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило (Yahoo!).

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

.*..среди последователей которых **такие** известные личности,  **как Стив Джобс из Apple, а также Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило из Yahoo!***

1) Союзное слово ***которых*** в середине предложения не отделяется запятой.

2) Запятая ставится в парных вариантах вида ***такой известный, как.***..

Comment: А если оставлять изначальный вариант, правильно ли использовать тире после"как", перед перечислением?

Comment: Нет, тире нельзя оставить.  С тире нужен другой вариант: .среди последователей которых всем  известные личности - Стив Джобс из Apple, а также Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило из Yahoo!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Вы считаете, тире лучше двоеточия, Sharon, в последнем Вашем варианте (в комментарии)?

Comment: Двоеточие требует особой предупредительной интонации (понижения голоса перед перечислением), а здесь скорее присоединительная конструкция:  однородный ряд в конце сложного предложения.

Comment: Ну ладно, спасибо!)

Answer (score 1):

**...среди последователей которых такие известные личности, как Стив Джобс из Apple, Джерри Янг и Дэвид Фило из Yahoo!**

Запятую с пробелом в начале надо заменить многоточием: какие бы знаки ни были до первого слова, если фраза приведена не сначала, ставят исключительно многоточие. За ним без пробела идёт текст. (После многоточия в конце предложения следующая фраза уже отделяется пробелом.)

Вариант Sharon с "а также" очень хорош, но оставлю, как написал сначала.

Про запятую после "которых" (которая не нужна) тоже уже сказано.

Тире не нужно, а если и ставите его, лучше применять код Alt 0151, чем ставить два дефиса подряд. Лучше уж один (отделённый пробелами, конечно же).

Про запятую в "такой известный, как" Sharon сказала.

На конце либо восклицательный знак, либо точка. Ставить оба знака — нонсенс.

Comment: А если этот символ используется в названии компании Yahoo!, точка все равно не ставится, как окончание предложения?

Comment: Сложный вопрос! Я бы тогда *Yahoo!* заключил в кавычки или выделил курсивом или полужирным или и тем и другим. Если поставить кавычки, тогда точка в конце будет правильной, а если делать выделение, я бы всё же оставил без неё.